# Is my password encrypted before it gets send to the database?

Tags: discord, discord.js, password-encryption

If I would like to encrypt a password and store that encrypted password to a cloud database. How does this process work in Discord?

1. Is the password send locally in plain text to the bot hosting. Encrypted there by the bot and then stored to the cloud db.

or

2. Is the password encrypted locally in the Discrod app and is the locally encrypted password then send by the bot to the cloud db.

Comment: i think usually passwords are encrypted on server side, client side encryption doesnt provide much security

Comment: passwords are not typically encrypted, that's a terrible security risk. If you must, use E2E where you feed the outside storage a ciphertext that the native Crypto API generates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discord (Like almost every web app) uses HTTPS protocol. So important data like passwords etc must be encrypted before sending (like you wrote in 2.). You can read more about SSL: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+ssl+works&oq=how+SSL+work&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.2239j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8.

If you want to see it on example, you can do it easily using Wireshark. Wireshark is app which shows you EVERYTHING what your device are sending and reciving. You can download it here from here (For Mac and Windows):
https://www.wireshark.org/download.html

Command for download it for linux:

```
sudo apt-get install wireshark
```

Comment: this would allow discord to see the sent password, is that desirable? it might be, it might not.